# AVR Micros and Millis

Tags: arduino, avr

I am working on a project and I am trying to prevent using any of the Arduino libraries since allot of them come with extra "Junk" and are not as fast as the core AVR libraries.

My question is if there is a AVR library that includes the equivalent of Arduino's millis() and micros() functions or if I need to write my own library?

I realize that I could use a timer and ISR to increment a value to keep track of the ticks but why reinvent the wheel if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is if there is a AVR library that includes the equivalent of Arduino's millis() and micros() functions or if I need to write my own library?

Since counting the time from startup will require configuration and use of a timer with custom code in the timer ISR (like you pointed out), you won't find a function like this in the AVR library.
Those libraries are not designed to hog a resource as general as a timer for something specific. This is a good example where Arduino libraries may provide a easy start, but break down as soon as you need a more control over a  resource that the libs use internally (like using timer0 for something custom).

Comment: So in short No.... ;-)  It does make sense since all of the timers can be used for something custom like you pointed out. One other question I have is wouldn't trying to get a very small resolution for the timer end up blocking the rest of the code since the ISR would basically always be firing and is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Define "very small resolution" ;) But yes, in general it would be best to limit the resolution to what you really need. An ISR blocks the main execution path and potentially even other interrupts (depending on interrupt priority). This is the reason why the ISR should contain as few instructions as possible. At 10MHz you get about 10 instructions per microsecond execution speed. So aiming for something like 1us resolution would be unrealistic. 10us timer interval sounds reasonable if the ISR is held short. You would have 100 instructions per timer tick, where maybe 20-30 are lost to the ISR.

Comment: If there are other some other interrupts that need attention (USART, TWI or other TIMERs), I wouldn't go above 100us or even 1ms to be somewhat safe.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my alibvr library.

The system clock part is more or less finished.

It uses C++ functionality (mostly templates) for computing values during compile time.  So you will need to use avr-g++.

See the [clock Readme](https://github.com/close2/alibvr/blob/master/README_CLOCK.md) for more information.

Even if you don't intend to use the library the clock.h file will help you writing your own system clock.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the util/delays.h that comes with the avr gcc installation that will provide you the same functionality as millis and micros
The only thing to remember is to set parameter F_CPU to right CPU frequency.

Comment: The `avr/delay.h` provides `_delay_ms` and `_delay_us`, but there is nothing to get time since start in milliseconds or microseconds (as `millis()` and `micros()` do).

Comment: delay() (blocking) is rather the opposite functionality to millis() (nonblocking) than the same ;)